# How can I convert a raster geotiff from EGM96 to WGS84 Ellipsoid Height Datum using the C++ gdal library

Tags: c++, gdal

I have used the C++ gdal library to read a raster image.  Specifically I've read hgt and geotiffs at this point.  The default vertical datum for those file types is most often EGM96 geoid.  I need to be able to use the C/C++ gdal library to convert to height above the WGS84 ellipsoid to compare with the data from my GPS.  I know I can get the job done at the command line with gdalwarp ([page 71 of this pdf](https://gdal.org/gdal.pdf)) but I'd prefer to be able to use any user input without the requirement to run a pre-processing script.  I'll do a system call if I have to, but shouldn't there be a way to get it done inside my application with the c++ library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GDAL Algorithms API for [GDAL warp](https://gdal.org/api/gdal_utils.html#gdal__utils_8h_1ab2094d5332364d63e0851dcb12398469) to warp the raster, but it would make much more sense to instead transform your GPS data to the raster you are using. There is a [tutorial here](https://gdal.org/tutorials/osr_api_tut.html).